# Table data not getting migrated while using AWS DMS to migrate data from Amazon Aurora RDS to Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I have been trying to migrate the data from my source endpoint which is an Amazon RDS DB instance to my target endpoint which is Amazon Redshift.

I am step-by-step following everything mentioned in the docs and my table is getting migrated successfully but unfortunately the data present in the table is not being reflected in the Amazon Redshift instance.

The table migration is successful, but when I click on the table statistics option, then the number of inserts is 0. That means although the table and schema were migrated but not the data.

[image: Table Statistics]

Have you faced this situation? If yes, what are the ways to fix this?

Comment: please add some detail. What are the stats for that table showing in DMS? what is missing exactly?

Comment: The table migration is successful, but when I click on the table statistics option, then the number of inserts is 0. That means although the table and schema were migrated but not the data.

Comment: check the table to make sure there are rows. check using the same credentials as being used by dms. check the migrations options to ensure that they are not filtering rows. check the migration type to ensure that it is "migrate existing data". check the target table preparation mode. check the logs (you did click to enable cloudwatch logs right?). ideally post the whole thing in json format into your question.